# Do games like Starcraft 2 use Windows Forms to build their UI?

Tags: c#, .net

This may be a dumb question...

When I log into Starcraft 2 and see that beautiful UI, I can't help but wonder if it's designed using Windows Forms (.Net or C#).  Is the login box just some kind of Windows dialog or do they do their own thing - whatever that may be?

Is it possible to get that much customization within Windows Forms?

Comment: Generally they're OpenGL/DirectX UI elements, drawn and handled directly through the graphics pipeline.

Comment: I got a chuckle out of imagining "not enough minerals" in a crappy alert box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  They use DirectX.  DirectX bypasses normal windows and operates at alower level.

You can customize a form to a great degree.  You have full control over painting it to look however you want.

Comment: I'd like to build something of an auto login for my local Starcraft 2 as a project to help me learn C#.  Is that possible given it's written with DirectX?

Answer (score 5):

No. Games and other apps that use DirectX to take control of the video device don't use WinForms or even the Win32 API for screen output.

StarCraft 2 most likely implements its own windowing and UI system, completely independent of the Windows API or WinForms library.

Yes, you can write an app in C# to perform similar DirectX graphics output, but using DirectX is not as simple as working with WinForms. I wouldn't recommend attempting to write a DirectX app as a way to teach yourself C# unless you are already very experienced with DirectX through other languages or tools (C++, mostly).

WinForms is fine for learning C# and whatever IDE tool chain you choose to use. After you're comfortable with C# patterns and terminology, then tackle learning how to write DirectX code with C#.